Is the derivative of a $C^1$ function nonzero almost everywhere on almost every level set?
Note: Here $\mathcal H^k$ denotes the $k$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.
Let $f \in C^1 (\mathbb \Omega)$ for some open, connected, bounded subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^n$. We consider for each $t \in \mathbb R$ the level set $E_t := \{x \in \Omega \, | \, f(x) = t\}$.
Question: Is it true that for Lebesgue almost every $t \in \mathbb R$, we have $Df(x) \neq 0$ for $\mathcal H^{n-1}$-almost every $x \in E_t$?
Comments:

It is interesting to contrast the desired result to the fact that we have $Df = 0$, $\mathcal H^n$-a.e. on every level set $E_t$. Note that this is not a contradiction!

The desired result is true for $f \in C^n (\Omega)$ by Sard's theorem.



For more smooth functions Sard's theorem says that for almost all $t$ we have $Df\ne 0$ on $E_t$

@FedorPetrov Indeed, in a later edit I added that additional remark.

Isn't it true that if $t$ is a regular value, then $Df$ is never zero on $E_t$; and $E_t$ has a positive $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ measure because it is a $C^1$ submanifold of dimension $n-1$?

@KhashF The first statement is indeed true, and Sard’s theorem says that almost every $t$ is a regular point. However Sard’s only applies for smooth enough functions, $C^n$ in this case. The second statement is not true as stated, though something similar does hold. The keywords are $C^1$ Sard’s lemma.

@NateRiver Thanks for clarification.

Why is the second statemnent of @KlashF's not true?

@GiorgioMetafune Oh, I think I misread his second statement as saying something else. It is true. I guess he wanted to use it to conclude a contradiction by Sard’s theorem.

It follows from co-area formula:
$$
\int_A |Df|=\int_{\mathbb R} \mathcal H^{n-1} (\{f=t\}\cap A).
$$
By taking  $A=\{|Df|= 0\}$ one gets that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \mathcal H^{n-1} (\{f=t\}\cap \{|Df|=0\})=0
$$
and thus  ,for a.e. $t$,
$$
\mathcal H^{n-1} (\{f=t\}\cap \{|Df|=0\})=0
$$

Oh dang that is nifty. Thanks!
